# Video connector connect

Tags: vidyo

Everyone I am using vidyo library in android. I am able to see preview but not able to connect to api. Anyone can help me. I generate token with cmd in Windows. There is any problem with vidyo library versions. Please Tell me which version work for Android 6.0.

Comment: I am using old version because I am not able to see preview with latest version in android 6.0.

Comment: Please tell me which type of problem is coming to connecting with api and why I am not able to see preview with latest version of library in android 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy paste the error messages shown on the console? 
The most common error during connecting is an invalid token. Double check if the token is valid. to test you can create a token on this helper website - https://vidyocreatetoken.appspot.com/
Note, in your username **do not** include any special characters (especially '@'). And get your developer key and app Id from the vidyo dashboard - https://developer.vidyo.io/dashboard

Comment: I have download many version of  VidyoClient-AndroidSDK then i fount that 4.1.13.4 and older version work for me. Now this is new problem so i am not able to use latest version . i am getting error in this line     vc = new VidyoConnector(videoFrame,VidyoConnector.VidyoConnectorViewStyle.VIDYO_CONNECTORVIEWSTYLE_Default, 16, "", "", 0);

Comment: I also want to know how i can get or generate  token in android studio. Without using cmd and  https://vidyocreatetoken.appspot.com/

Comment: i used Library - generateToken.jar in android studio. 

Library code-
class GenerateToken then i found error in this line
String payload = String.join(DELIM, PROVISION_TOKEN, jid, expires, vcard);              errror-------------------cannot resolve join method                                                                                                                     

Android studio 3.0.1 is not able to Resolve String.join()
how i can solve it.

Comment: I am not able to generate token in my android application using android studio.

Comment: Ideally you should be creating your token in your server backend. That ways you can ensure that your developer key and app Id is secure. Do you have a servers side component?